# how to render a controller with several arguments in twig?

Tags: symfony, render, twig

How would you do this with several arguments on the "with"?

I am trying to get this one to work...

Controller:

```
public function BeforeSlideAction($template,$order) {
```

Twig:

```
{% render "BizTVScreenDisplayBundle:Default:BeforeSlide" with { 'template': c.template.id, 'order': i } %}
```

And I get an error saying arg2 ($order) is missing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermid!

Turns out 'order' is a reserved word (in TWIG?) that is what caused the error. Changed it to ordernumber and I'm fine =)